# How to import three-js-csg in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

Firstly I use:

```
npm install three --save
npm install @types/three
npm install three-js-csg --save
```

after that:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as csg from 'three-js-csg';


let sphere1BSP = new csg(sphere1);
let cube2BSP = new csg(cube);
let resultBSP = sphere1BSP.subtract(cube2BSP);
```

But it has thrown below exception:

> core.js:1633 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   sphere1BSP.subtract is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the npm page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-js-csg it looks like you may need to instantiate 'three-js-csg' with **THREE**.

```
import THREE from 'three';
import * as csg from 'three-js-csg';
const ThreeBSG = csg(THREE);
```

**I did not test this though, so I may be mistaken.**